# simplifying a LEFT / REPLACE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that is in dire need of being simplified. Here is part of the query:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME, CharIndex( ' ', MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME + ' ' ) - 1)

    , CharIndex( ' ', LEFT(MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME, CharIndex( ' ', MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME + ' ' ) - 1) + ' ' ) - 1)

    +REPLICATE(' ',25),25)+
    LEFT(' '+REPLICATE(' ',20),20)+
    LEFT(

    LEFT(

    LEFT(MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME, CharIndex( ',', MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME + ',' ) - 1)

    , CharIndex( ',', LEFT(MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME, CharIndex( ',', MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME + ',' ) - 1) + ',' ) - 1)
```

the reason I am doing the `replicates` is because i am building a fixed length string. each column needs to be a fixed length.

in addition to the above query, for every occurrence of `MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME` and `MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME` i need to do:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME,', MD',''),',MD','')
```

and

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME,', MD',''),',MD','')
```

How do I include these `REPLACES` in the query and simplify the entire thing?

thanks so much for your guidance and kind help.

Answer (score 1):

select the common bits in a subquery... (you'll have a bit more)

```
SELECT
    LEFT(REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME, fname_idx - 1)
    , CharIndex( ' ', LEFT(MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME, fname_idx - 1) + ' ' ) - 1)
..
FROM ( select CharIndex( ' ', MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME + ' ' ) fname_idx, REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME from...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a subquery will help with the syntax.  In addition, you can cast to a CHAR() to pad and truncate strings to a given length.

I think the following does what you want:

```
SELECT cast(fname as char(25)) + ' ' + cast(lname as char(25))
from (select replace(replace(LEFT(MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME,
                                  CharIndex(' ', MLIS.REQUESTOR_FIRST_NAME + ' ' ) - 1
                                 ),
                             ',MD', ''),
                     ', MD', '') as fname,
             replace(relpace(left(MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME,
                                  CharIndex(',', MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME + ',' ) - 1),
                                  CharIndex(',', LEFT(MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME,
                                                      CharIndex( ',', MLIS.REQUESTOR_LAST_NAME + ',' ) - 1) + ','
                                                               ) - 1
                                 ),
                             ',MD', ''),
                     ', MD', '') as lname
```

However, it is hard to follow the original query, and there might be a syntax error.  This query is meant to give you some guidance on solving the problem.  I would also put a cast after the concatenate to be sure the final string is the right length.